# cakephp call a controller function in view file

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

My method is

```
public function topmenu($parentsid=null){
            $this->layout =false;
            $category_tree  = $this->Categorymaster->find('all',array('order'=>'Categorymaster.lft ASC','conditions'=>array('Categorymaster.parent_id'=>$parentsid)));
            echo '<ul class="sub-menu" role="menu">';
            foreach($category_tree as $parentval){
                echo '<li>'.$parentval['Categorymaster']['name'].'</li>';
                $id = $parentval['Categorymaster']['id'];
                $haschild = $this->Categorymaster->children($id, true);
                if (!empty($haschild)) {
                    $this->topmenu($id);
                }
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            $this->set(compact('category_tree'));
            $this->render('topmenu');
        }
```

I get output from controller

[image]

I am trying to use a `foreach` loop in my topmenu.ctp file but as cakephp
is mvc it gives error at the lines

```
$haschild = $this->Categorymaster->children($id, true);
                    if (!empty($haschild)) {
                        $this->topmenu($id);
}
```

so how can it use `topmenu()` method in .ctp file so that i can show it in my menu or any other alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all its never a good practice to call controller method directly in ctp (view) file.

If you still want to do this, try to call like this:-

```
Controller name::(scope resolution operator) function name(parameters).
```

Note:-**Make sure that your method is public.**